# Counting articles from 3 sentences

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, count

Counting Definite and Indefinite articles

This is what I have right now. I am new to this and I think i have to do something with array?? So my first question is how to turn the input into a list.

```
import sys
    def main():
        indefinite = 0
        definite = 0
        article = ""

        for line in sys.stdin:
            line  = line.strip()

            for word in line.split():
                if article == 'een' in line:
                    indefinite = indefinite + 1
                if article == 'het' in line:
                    definite   = definite + 1
                if article == 'de' in line: 
                    definite   = definite + 1

        print(indefinite)
        print(definite)
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements are wrong because you're not using the `for` variable `word`, it should be `if word=='xxx':` or even better you can skip at all the if statement and use `indefinite+=(word=='een')` and `definite+=(word=='het') or (word=='de')` using the fact that True is 1 and False is 0

Below a more "Pythonic" version of your program (my code is Python 2.7 need a little conversion to work in Python 3):

```
import re, itertools, sys

def main():
    indefinite = 0
    definite = 0

    for line in sys.stdin:
        # regular expression to find articles in line
        # match is a list with all the articles found
        match=re.findall(r"\been|de|het\b",line,re.I)

        # list compreension to create an articles dictionary
        # itertools.groupby make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable.
        articles={k: len(list(g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(match)}

        # count definite/indefinite articles
        for k in articles.keys():
            if k in ['het','de']:
                definite+=articles[k]
            else:
                indefinite+=articles[k]

    print "%d definite articles, %d indefinite articles" % (definite, indefinite)

main()
```